# Get api object and place it into html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I put my API get's return value onto an html page?

If I do:

```
const url = "https://alloysystems.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets";
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
    "authorization": "Basic ILLNEVERGIVEYOUMYKEYKEYLOL"
    }
})
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

I get a bunch of objects, (I think) in the console log:
[image]

However if I try to add the data to html tag so I can see it on a webpage, I either get a failure or I get `[Object],[Object]`

Attempted code:
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Today's Date</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
let d = new Date();

const url = "https://alloysystems.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets";
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
    "authorization": "Basic ILLNEVERGIVEYOUMYKEYKEYLOL"
    }
})
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + data + "</h1>")
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an object so if you want to show everything of it between the h1 tag you need to stringify it first like so :

```js
.then(data => document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "</h1>")
```

If you just want to show the type for example you need to specify that part like so:

```js
.then(data => document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>" + data.type + "</h1>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it from an Object to JSON using

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

If you want to show it formatted (multiline and indented) on the html page, put in inside a `<pre>` tag.

See example below in the snippet

```js
fetch(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=2&page=1`
  )
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((d) => {
    const pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(d, null, `\t`)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(pre);
  });
```

```css
body,
pre {
  color: white;
  background: #0080ff;
  font-family: Calibri
}
```